# How to rename genymotion device?

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

My virtual device is called `phone 720*1280`, I want to rename it to `client phone`. However cant find a settings for that
if I rename folder inside .Genymobile/genymotion/deployed - device is missing from list of availible devices
changes in field inside `phone 720*1280.xml` (name, vm_device_name) does not see to make any effect.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use GenyMotion pretty often, and I, too, was curious about this. I was able to successfully rename one of my GenyMotion VMs by doing the following:

1. Close GenyMotion completely (*may not be necessary, but mine was fully closed when I tried this*)
2. Open VirtualBox (the "*Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager*")
3. In the list of virtual machines, **right click** on the GenyMotion VM you want to rename
4. In the context menu that appears, click on "*Settings...*"
5. Make sure you are on the "*Basic*" tab of the "*General*" section
6. Modify the text inside of the "*Name*" textbox/text-field to whatever you want
7. Finally, just click the "*OK*" button at the bottom of the window.

When you open GenyMotion, you should now see the device listed with whatever name you entered inside of VirtualBox.

I personally tested this on Window 10 64bit, with VirtualBox v5.0.8 (r103449), and GenyMotion v2.5.4. After following the steps above, I was able to successfully rename an Android VM and use it in GenyMotion.

**Note**: This does also appear to rename the folder. Hopefully that will not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this,and it worked for me:

1. xxx.vbox & xxx.vbox-prev in Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\xxx;
2. open these two files, you may got this:
     *Machine uuid=".." name="xxx" OSType="Linux"*
   just modify the "name" & save, done.